# Как отследить разницу в изменении данных при запросе с api?

Tags: vue.js

Есть список из 3 объектов, которые я получаю по запросу с api. Если на сервере, в базе, к этим 3 объектам добавят еще 2 объекта, при ререндере я получу вообщем 5 объектов. Как отследить/получить только разницу? Интересуют именно последние 2 добавленных объекта. На vue.

Comment: у вас есть список из трёх объектов. Вам приходит список из 5 объектов. Вы можете найти разницу, сравнив эти два списка. Это вопрос не к vue, а к умению вами программировать на js

Comment: Вариантов сравнить массивы масса, если лень или не знаете как, то посмотрите в сторону lodash.